# Graph API получение списка друзей

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

пытаюсь получить список друзей, но получаю ошибку

```
public void graphApiGetFriends() {
        AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Facebook token: " + token.getToken());
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/{friend-list-id}",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        /* handle the result */
                        Log.wtf(TAG, "Response error: " + response.getError());
                        Log.wtf(TAG, "Raw: " + response.getRawResponse());
                        Log.wtf(TAG, "Array: " + response.getJSONArray());
                        Log.wtf(TAG, "Object: " + response.getJSONObject());
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
}
```

И ловлю:

```
Response error: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {friend-list-id}}
```

Меняю на `friend-list-id` и получаю тоже самое, есть как минимум один друг у которого установлено приложение и он залогинился

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем проблема была в том, что путь был указан неправильно и отсутствовал мой `Facebook Id` в начале пути.
В итоге запрос выглядит так:

```
/**
 * Request to GrapApi for get friends list
 */
public void graphApiGetFriends() {
    AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    String userId = token.getUserId();
    String path  = "/friends";
    new GraphRequest(
            token,
            userId + path,
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    /* handle the result */
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "Response error: " + response.getError());
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "Raw: " + response.getRawResponse());
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
}
```

В ответе на запрос приходит список друзей у которых установлено приложение.